# Running GAE remote_api_shell.py in a iPython notebook web interface

Tags: google-app-engine, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to run modified remote_api_shell.py in an iPython notebook web interface, so that non-technical users with a basic grasp of Python could have read-only access to our production database.

Has anyone set something like this up, and what's the best way of going about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPython Notebook has profile directories in `~/.ipython`, which have a `startup` directory for Python scripts that can be used to do the customization of `sys.path` and login credentials as `remote_api_shell.py` does.

Comment: Could you provide an working example of how to connect to gae remote api shell. I'm getting the below error

HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-50417ac81b7d> in <module>()
----> 1 connect_to_gae()

/home/sirimala/.ipython/profile_default/startup/ipython_startup.py in connect_to_gae()
     20             APP_NAME + '.appspot.com',  # servername
     21             '/_ah/remote_api',  # path
---> 22             secure=True
     23         )

HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized Too many auth attempts.

Comment: Don't have a working one right now, but it's definitely possible! Good luck :-)